# Does anyone know of a light icon font similar to The Elegant Icon Font by Elegant Themes?

Tags: icon, web-fonts, font-recommendation

Basically what I am looking for is a **light version** of this icon-font: http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/elegant-icon-font

[image]

Anyone know where I can find something like that? Freebie or not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found exactly what I was looking for here: 
http://themes-pixeden.com/font-demos/7-stroke/index.html

About

- They are free
- Great documentation

Comment: I was about to suggest checking Pixeden, but you found it already. :)